# How to run yasm in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, assembler

I recently have installed YASM but I cannot find any *yasm* in PC.

Also, it was written that it would through terminal. However, I have no idea what it was about.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type:

```
yasm --help
```

> YASM consists of the **yasm command**, libyasm, the core backend library, and a large number of modules. Currently, libyasm and the loadable modules are statically built into the yasm executable.

Comment: Yes it does. Though parts of the help section might have been included into the answer to make it a good answer ;)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini `yasm --help` and `yasm -help` is the same in **this** case.

Answer (score 2):

### yasm – The Yasm Modular Assembler

First, open a terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or search in Unity Dash/GNOME Activities for *Terminal*

---

Now you can find the binary (using the terminal) via

```
which yasm
```

*Sample output*

```
/usr/bin/yasm
```

Yasm has no frontend or a `desktop` file and therefore there is no entry in your Unity Dash, GNOME Activities and so on.

---

*Usage*

```
yasm foo
```

where foo contains some assembler code. The command creates a file `foo.o`. Make it executable with

```
chmod +x foo.o
```

and run with

```
./foo.o
```

---

More infos via

```
man yasm
```